# The Greater Good

Tags: discussion, answers, voting

Yesterday I was the first to answer [this SQL question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18199734/convert-linq-statement-to-sql/18199886#18199886). I answered off the top of my head and didn't have SSMS nearby to give a more... optimized answer, so I gave one that works, but that uses a `CASE WHEN`.

Then another (relatively new) user comes along and posts an answer that merely complements mine, literally "or you can do it without a `CASE WHEN` like this...".

I think his answer should really have been a comment under mine, and then I would have edited my post accordingly. But it wasn't, so instead of editing my post and making his answer moot (and incomplete), I gave him an upvote because his `WHERE` clause *was indeed* better written than mine and, if I had taken the time to optimize my answer, I'd have come up with something very similar.

This morning I check out the question to follow-up, and see he's scored 2 more upvotes while my answer is sitting unnoticed, probably awaiting a downvote for using a `CASE WHEN`.

Should I remove my upvote and edit my answer? I had upvoted the other user's answer and not edited mine in a "sportsmanship" spirit, so that this new user would feel encouraged to post... but I don't know if it was the *right* thing to do.

What's the Greater Good?

- Edit my answer and make it a better post (remove my upvote and p!ss off that user?)
- Leave all as is and (perhaps) make someone else's day (and hope not to get downvoted?)

The bottom line is, as far as I can tell, my answer addresses the OP's question, his answer addresses my suboptimal WHERE clause. Should I have flagged it as "not an answer"?

Comment: For reference - You can't remove your upvote on an answer unless that answer has been edited since you voted.

Comment: What I personally would do is add the extra contextual information from my answer into his answer, and then delete mine. Then you'd have a single, complete, correct answer.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that he comes from a forum environment. The only change I'd make is to edit out the "Another way,". Order is not preserved, and it seems out of place. Other than that, all seems fine. No changes/flags/(undone) votes needed.

Comment: @CodyGray Just did that... and the edit was rejected!

Comment: Yeah [can't say I'm entirely surprised](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2711637)

Comment: Note the 2nd reviewer thought it was too minor???

Comment: Err, oops! Sorry, I didn't realize you didn't have full editing privileges on Stack Overflow. There are so many bad ones, people don't know a good edit when it hits them in the face. I'll fix that for you...

Comment: Yeah, can't wait to get there! Re-deleted my post then :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd leave it as is.

It is an alternative and that is good. It adds useful info to the question. If you edited your answer to the same as the other one, then it would be obsolete.

Comment: Ok then. I tried editing the other user's post but it was rejected as it "changed too much of the original post". So leaving it all as is then.

Comment: You... tried to change it to a CREATE PROCEDURE statement.

Comment: Well yeah, so that the answer would address the OP's post, not mine! The provided SQL snippet doesn't define `@variable1`, it's "assumed" the SQL is sitting in a CREATE PROCEDURE statement...

Comment: If your answer is different enough you you'd need to make that big of an edit to make the other user's better, you should probably just keep your own answer IMO.